# why is the coordinate vector of p = (7p1,-8p1,1p1) and not (7p1,-1p1,2p1)? (probably quick question)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

why is the coordinate vector of p = (7p1,-8p1,1p1) and not (7p1,-1p1,2p1)? (probably quick question)

I've looked at my book 5 times already to confirm the formula coordinate vector relevent to S is (p)s = a(p1) + b(p2) + c(p3)

which leads to a system of equations

1a 1b 1c = 7

0a 1b 1c = -1

0a 0b 1c = -2

which solved yields (p)s = (-5, -3 2)

.... but p and (p)s are different in answer..

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

With the representation $(7,-1,2)$ you presumably mean that it is with respect to the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$. 
It would then mean that it is really: 
$$7\cdot 1 + (-1)\cdot x + 2\cdot x^2=7-x+2x^2$$

However, the representation $(7,-8,3)_S$ is with respect to the basis $S=\{1+x+x^2,x+x^2,x^2\}$.
It means that it is really:
$$7(1+x+x^2) + (-8)(x+x^2) + 3(x^2)=7-x+2x^2$$
which is what was specified for $\mathbf p$.

Comment: oh, ok. but how am I supposed to find the numbers  (7,−8,3) to begin with?

Comment: In this particular case part of the base vectors do not overlap. Only $p_1$ has a component without any $x$ in it. So you can tell that the first number has to be $7$. Subtract $7\mathbf p_1$ from $\mathbf p$ to see what is left and then try to find the second number.